# How to count and mulitplicate checkbox rows in a array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have three checkbox in every row and want to count checked checkbox in a row and multiply it with the next row.
Ex.
First row 2 checkbox checked  1+1
second row one checkbox checked   1
third row three checkbox checked 1+1+1
sum: 2*1*3=6 
I'm understand that I have to put it in an array and trough it.
I hope you understand?
I'm new on programing.
hmm i tried an array and it didnt worked
https://jsfiddle.net/6nbrxd2w/

`

```js
$('.cb').on('change', function(){ // on change of state
   Updatesum();
});

function Updatesum() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  $('.cb:checked').each(function(){
     sum += Number($(this).val()); 
  })
 
 $('#totalsum').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<html>

<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id='game1' value="1"  >Game 1 (1)<input type="checkbox" class="cb"id='game1' value="1" >Game 1 (1)<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id='game1' value="1"> Game 1(1)<br>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id='game2' value="1"  >Game 2 (1)<input type="checkbox" class="cb"id='game2' value="1" >Game 2 (1)<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id='game2' value="1"> Game 2(1)<br>
<input type="text" id="totalsum" value="">
<input type="text" id="total" value="">
```

Javascript

```js
$('.cb').on('change', function(){ // on change of state
   Updatesum();
});

function Updatesum() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  $('.cb:checked').each(function(){
     sum += Number($(this).val()); 
  })
 
 $('#totalsum').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

`

Comment: Seems that you are on your way! Be creative now and figure it out. A quickie would be that you put input inside a div and give the div class of the column integer. Then you select over it and do your math. Another is that you populate the html through an array and assign some values you recognize so you can fetch them. Be creative! :)

Comment: 1. **Never have duplicate ids on a webpage**  Remove all `#game1` and `#game2` ids. 2. **See number 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your code:

```js
$('.cb1 , .cb2, .cb3').on('change', function(){
   Updatesum();
});

function Updatesum() {
  var sum1 = 0 ,sum2 = 0 ,sum3 = 0 ;
 /*  $('.cb:checked').each(function(){
     sum += Number($(this).val()); 
  }) */
    $('.cb1:checked').each(function(){
   // alert('hi');
     sum1 += Number($(this).val()); 
  })

    $('.cb2:checked').each(function(){
     sum2 += Number($(this).val()); 
  })

   $('.cb3:checked').each(function(){
     sum3 += Number($(this).val()); 
  })

 $('#totalsum').val(sum1+sum2+sum3);
  $('#total').val(sum1*sum2*sum3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1"  value="1" />Game 1 (1)
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1"  value="1" />Game 1 (1)
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1"  value="1"/> Game 1(1)
<br>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb2" value="1"  />Game 2 (1)
<input type="checkbox" class="cb2" value="1" />Game 2 (1)
<input type="checkbox" class="cb2" value="1"/> Game 2(1)
<br>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb3"  value="1"  />Game 3 (1)
<input type="checkbox" class="cb3"  value="1" />Game 2 (1)
<input type="checkbox" class="cb3" value="1"/> Game 3(1)
<br>

<input type="text" id="totalsum" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="total" value=""/>
```

js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6nbrxd2w/

Comment: Great! So If I have 13 rows maybe it better to make a  loop ?

Comment: I tried this with an array but I think I'm missing somethings.

$('.cb1').on('change', function(){
Updatesumma();
});

function Updatesumma() {
var sum1 = 0;
var rowAmount = [];
rows = new Array(13);
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    //rowAmount[i] = rows[i].filter(check => check === true).length
    rowAmount[i] = rows[i].$('.cb1:checked')
}
var totalAmount = 0;
for (i = 0; i < rowAmount.length; i++) {
    totalAmount *= rowAmount;
}
  $('#total').val(totalAmount);
}

https://jsfiddle.net/6nbrxd2w/

Comment: correct  fiddle 



jsfiddle.net/wba123/pzbnvd4c/30